# Can a linear classifier represent logic gates requiring more than one operator?

Tags: machine-learning

For example how do you get the 0 and 1 table that represents  for example a OR (b AND NOT c).  I under the individual logic gates but how does put the pieces together. I've tried but to no avail.
 [image]

Comment: What have you tried? What language are you trying to do this in?

Comment: It is not a coding proplem I need to to determine whether the logic gate can be represented by by a linear classifier. For example I know how the AND logic gate is represented. I know how the NAND logic gate is represented but I don't understand how to get the truth table for the problem highlighted.

Comment: Is your question then something along the lines of "Can a linear classifier be used to parametrize any Boolean function?" If so, you should update the question to make it more clear what you're asking. Also, StackOverflow isn't the most appropriate site for that if it's a theoretical question; the CS stack exchange would probably be better. And the answer is no, a linear classifier can't be used for any Boolean function. You can see this easily by considering the function y = x1 XOR x2 (drawing it out should make it clear).

Comment: There's a graph of the points and a truth table of the XOR problem at the end of [this page](http://www.ece.utep.edu/research/webfuzzy/docs/kk-thesis/kk-thesis-html/node19.html).

Comment: Yes this is what I'm trying to determine. I did not wish to phrase the question in such a way as to get the answer since I was more concerned in deriving at the answer my self with a worked example.  Your response made me realise I was right in solution but I did not trust my solution given how solving  the problem  was explained in the forum.  Accordingly, I will amend the question.  Thanks for much.

Answer (score 0):

Check this example. You can break your expression to few steps to easily understand each step.

[image: boolean table]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a general method to find a linear decision function. What you can do is training a linear classifier on the boolean table and see the result.
A possible decision function for OR could be:

```
if A+B-0.5>0:
    return 1
else:
    return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interesting link related to your question:

It is possible to use neural networks to represent some logic gates like XOR.

https://towardsdatascience.com/how-neural-networks-solve-the-xor-problem-59763136bdd7

Basically, this link, explains the methodology taken in the book deep learning p.171 (Ian Goodfellow, Yoshua Bengio, Aaron Courville) Where the author is trying to learn XOR function. No matter how you try to place your decision boundary you will have a miss label (coordinates can't be on the decision boundary). Has your you can see in the first image:  [XOR with decision boundary attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ztvwl.png). They will train an MSE loss function on a 2 layers network.

However, I think this question is more directed toward the math stack exchange. Here is a link if you want to learn more : https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/11589/creating-neural-net-for-xor-function/19799#19799

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).